# Linked resource absolute paths in generated makefiles in eclipse cdt

Tags: eclipse, path, makefile, external, eclipse-cdt

I am trying to add external cpp files as linked resources to an eclipse CDT project. I have managed to have relative paths for these cpp files in the eclipse project (files), but these are automatically expanded into absolute paths in the generated makefiles. We use the makefiles in a continuous integration system, where these absolute paths are not acceptable.
I have tried to set up these paths to be relative to build variables, environment variables and even linux system variables, without success.
Any idea? Thanks.