# Configure Eclipse CDT to generate makefiles with relative sources paths

Tags: eclipse, path, makefile, eclipse-cdt

Somebody already asked this question but no answer was provided. Does anyone have a solution/workaround?

[Linked resource absolute paths in generated makefiles in eclipse cdt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22064413/linked-resource-absolute-paths-in-generated-makefiles-in-eclipse-cdt)

Comment: Like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3997152/getting-eclipse-cdt-to-use-relative-include-paths-in-generated-makefiles

Comment: No. Problem affects sources paths.

Comment: Still not fixed in 2023?  Some of my source folders are "Linked Resources" with "Variable Relative Location" (i.e. PROJECT_LOC\..\..\src\app).  But they still show full path in the generated makefiles on Windows (i.e. C:/repos/fw/src/app/timer.c) and Linux (i.e. /home/phatpaul/repos/fw/app/timer.c).

Answer (score 0):

Nobody answered because there is no good answer :(
CDT does not really work well with linked resources, you have two options
a) do not use linked resources
b) contribute patch to CDT to fix this
https://wiki.eclipse.org/CDT/contributing

Answer (score 0):

I posted a solution on this question which I used and works for me in the Git-lab CI yaml script.[Getting CDT to use relative path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3997152/getting-eclipse-cdt-to-use-relative-include-paths-in-generated-makefiles)